# Does specifying that you are LGBT increase your chances of an interview?

Tags: job-search, lgbtq

Since we're all (or atleast, some of us are) working with the benefit of anonymity, I would like to ask the hiring managers: if a candidate lists himself as gay and your workforce has a deficit in diversity, would it increase his chances of getting hired?

Comment: Can you add details about where you are based and your type of role? The idea of 'diversity quotas' is definitely not a worldwide one and some places the exact opposite (i.e. *not* getting the job if you're LGBT+) is more likely. When would you be specifying this, on your CV or in interview?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I list LGBT clubs on my application](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12888/should-i-list-lgbt-clubs-on-my-application)

Comment: I could just imagine one industry where the sexual orientation of an applicant could have anything to do with how well they will perform in their job, and looking at your profile you don't seem to be looking for a job in adult entertainment.

Comment: Not all of us prefer anonymity :) Your private life may be important depending on the type of work you do. If you're an attorney working in civil rights, it might matter more. If you're a programmer (common among users of this site), it would not. What matters most are the skills you bring to the company. It would cause concern if your whole contribution to the company becomes defined by your sexual orientation, and not by your ability to perform the job well.

Comment: Is the fact that you're LGBT really the unusual thing or is it the fact that you're mentioning it all. For example, in the countless times I've introduced myself I've never felt it important to state "Oh yeah, and I prefer women 18-35!"

Comment: Hardly any company has a 'quota' of non-straight people. That's because most companies hire plenty of LGB people - even if they don't know it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I do a lot of hiring of coders. Even though I like diversity and love getting applications from people that doesn't fit into the standard mold (white 20-35 straight male), I would not like getting it stuffed in my face.

Seeing someone listing being LGBT in a resume would kind of make me think about if that person expects special treatment or expect being hired because of a diversity goal. Basically, being LGBT would be positive when you apply to me, but being too forward about it would negate that positive.

Comment: Seeing it _featured_ might surprise , unless I was hiring for a job like mass marketing where being familiar with other communities was a definite advantage. Seeing it as part of someone's activities/interests, I'd look at what they were doing with those interests -- leadership in an organization, or relevant skills, are positive+almost) no matter what the organization. But there will be people who react badly, or have issues with the specific organization, so it isn't risk free. Judgement call on that one, I'm afraid

Answer (score 8):

> if a candidate lists himself as gay and your workforce has a deficit in diversity, would it increase his chances of getting hired?

No. Personally I'd be a little worried that you are going to against me. It would not be the first time I've seen people come back with "you know I am <minority/> which is why you rejected me".

Answer (score 2):

You are asking a very speculative question, whose answer varies with each organization you are applying and within that organization, with each hiring manager you are interviewing with.

What increases your chances of getting hired are your credentials - work experience, skills set, education - your attitude and the persona you project, where your persona indicates how well you will fit into the position and with the company. No matter who you are and no matter what what you are. For example, you certainly don't want to project an "I don't suffer fools gladly" persona if you are going for a customer facing position.

Comment: 90% yes, there's still a lot of people who are simply there because they're diversity hires.